# Google app engine cron django failed after 30 seconds

Tags: django, google-app-engine, cron

I am trying to schedule a task on app engine using cron that will run continuously on background. I have written the cron task it works fine on local server but when I run it through google cloud console it failed after 30 seconds.

cron.yaml:

```
cron:
- description: daily tweets streaming
  url: /path/to/cron
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

views.py:

```
def testing(request):
    print("okasha---")
    from streamTweets import start_stream
    start_stream()
```

urls.py:

```
  url(r'^path/to/cron$', views.testing, name="testing"),
```

I have read a solution that says to divide the task into subtasks but i am not able to divide it into subtasks. My log says No entries found but when I access it directly by url it starts the script but after 30 seconds it gives 502 bad gateway error.

Comment: standard or flex env? what's your scaling config?

Comment: flex env with auto-scaling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run long cron jobs on App Engine flexible environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431806/how-to-run-long-cron-jobs-on-app-engine-flexible-environment)

Comment: But note that `An HTTP request invoked by cron can run for up to 60 minutes` - from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml. Not indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

Does your app use gunicorn?

gunicorn will by default use synchronised workers and kill them after 30 seconds.
On my Google App Engine app, it killed everything after 30 seconds regardless of if it's a cloud task or cron job.

2 possible ways to get around it are:

Use Async workers, see here: [How can I run long tasks on Google App Engine, which uses gunicorn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160535/how-can-i-run-long-tasks-on-google-app-engine-which-uses-gunicorn), I haven't tried it.

Or change the timeout for the synchronised workers, here is my app.yaml '--timeout=600' sets the gunicorn worker timeout.
This is for a Google App Engine Python 3 Standard App.

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --workers=4 --timeout=600

instance_class: B8

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 11
  idle_timeout: 10m

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

handlers:
 - url: '/.*'
   script: auto
```