# How can I run long tasks on Google App Engine, which uses gunicorn?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gunicorn

GAE flex uses gunicorn as an entrypoint by default which is fine, except I have a function that takes a very long time to process (scraping websites and story data in a db) and gunicorn times out at 30 seconds by default, then a new worker starts all over on the task, and so on and so forth.

I can set the gunicorn timeout to something like 20 minutes, but it doesn't seem graceful. Is there any way to run these backend functions "outside" of gunicorn, or perhaps a gunicorn config I'm not thinking about? There is no client side, so the long time to complete isn't an issue.

My **app.yaml** file currently looks like this:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 2

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment. 
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 3
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use async worker-class and then you won't need to set the timeout to 20 minutes. The default worker class is sync. Docs regarding the workers [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#choosing-a-worker-type).

Use the eventlet async worker (gevent not recommended if using google client libraries)

```
pip install eventlet
```

Then in your gunicorn instantiation set the worker-class = 'eventlet' and set number of workers to [number of cores] x 2 +1 (that's just a recommendation in [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#workers)).
For example:

```
CMD exec gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --workers 3 -b :$PORT main:app
```

[Gunicorn Worker Configuration](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes)

Alternatively, use implementation described [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/scalable-video-transcoding-with-app-engine-flexible-621f6e7fdf56) using pubsub and workers.

Comment: This works, but note that in a Flex environment, workers (requests and crons) are limited to 10 minutes. It's a hard limit. (See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed)

Comment: im sorry, but where does the 'CMD exec gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --workers 3 -b :$PORT main:app' exactly go?