# How to configure entrypoint in Python 3 to match Python 2 behavior?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm currently working on porting my app from GAE Python 2 to Python 3. I'd like the process/threading and scaling characteristics in Python 3 to match the Python 2 behavior. Specifically, I want the number of processes, threads, and 60 second timeout to match.

I set in app.yaml:

```yaml
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app -t 60 -w 1 --threads 8
```

As shown, the timeout is 60 seconds.

Also set is 1 worker and many threads, because multiple workers causes out-of-memory errors on requests, which did not occur in Python 2 runtime. Furthermore, from the Python 2 docs, it seems that they might have just used 1 worker and multiple threads:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref

Am I on track here? Did GAE Python 2 in fact use 1 process and many threads in threadsafe mode?

Comment: Gunicorn will by default use synchronized workers and kill them after 30 seconds, [here is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032193/google-app-engine-cron-django-failed-after-30-seconds). Additionally, UTF8 decoding inconsistency between P2 and P3 is a [known issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/70448), also [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard/pull/53).

Comment: Since posting the initial question, I learned that Gunicorn doesn't timeout when using multiple threads per worker. It only times out when the worker has a single thread. Also even when Gunicorn can time out, it just kills the process without allowing the request to gracefully fail. In GAE Python 2, it would raise a DeadlineExceededError in the request. That prevents the behavior I'm hoping for, and seems to work very different than GAE Python 2.

Comment: It seems that GAE Python 2 literally just re-implements core pieces of the Python runtime to accomplish this, such as its own Thread class:   https://github.com/arnesson/appengine-python-sdk/blob/master/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist27/threading.py

Comment: I found the magical solution for mimicing GAE Python 2's graceful deadline exceeded behavior: ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc

Comment: Could you post your solution for mimicking Python 2 behavior, as an answer? It is a Stack Overflow best practice.

Answer (score 0):

1. I 'believe' Python2.7 supported concurrent requests based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#concurrency_and_latency)
2. Regarding your comment - *multiple workers causes out-of-memory errors* - if you increase number of workers, then you probably have to use a higher class (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices))

Comment: Python 2.7 certainly supports concurrent requests. My question is mainly around whether it used multiple processes. Python 3 seems to run out of memory faster. Even with one worker.